# Sorting email accounts (IMAP above POP) in outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

My boss has asked me to try move his IMAP data file above his POP data file in the outlook mail view pane (We are using Office 2007)
Problem is no matter what I do "Personal Folders" remains above "Gmail".  Do you guys know if there is a fix, everything I have come across relates to either folder structure inside each given data file or moving the pst's instead.

As an example his Navigation pane would look something like this:

> *Personal Folders*
>
> - *folder*
> - *folder*
> - *folder*
> - *folder*
>
> *Gmail*
>
> - *folder*
> - *folder*
> - *folder*

He wants it so GMAIL is where "personal folders" is situated and vice versa. Personal folders is pop3 (naturally) and GMAIL is IMAP (obviously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've spoken with Microsoft finally. It seems that this is not possible until Office 2013. This is their official stance. So No fix.